# Há como retornar a um determinada linha de código?

Tags: python, if, for, while

Gostaria de saber se existe algum módulo, função, etc. que me permita voltar para uma determinada linha do código.

Tenho essa dúvida porque, sempre quando quero fazer uma pergunta repetidamente, tenho que colocar de novo a mesma variável, como acontece nas linhas 7 e 12

```
tupla = 'zero', 'um', 'dois', 'três', 'quatro', 'cinco', 'seis', 'sete', 'oito', 'nove', 'dez', 'onze',\
    'doze', 'treze', 'quatorze', 'quinze', 'dezesseis', 'dezessete', 'dezoito', 'dezenove', 'vinte'
for num in tupla:
    num = int(input('Digite um número: '))
    ext = tupla[num]
    print(f'Você digitou o número {ext}')
    opcao = str(input('Quer continuar a ler os números por extenso? [S/N] ')).upper().strip()
    while opcao == 'S':
        num = int(input('Então digita outro número: '))
        ext = tupla[num]
        print(f'Você digitou o número {ext}')
        opcao = str(input('Quer continuar a ler os números por extenso? [S/N] ')).upper().strip()
    while opcao == 'N':
        exit('Obrigado por usar nosso programa.')
```

Comment: Não entendi a pergunta, você já usa um laço de repetição [while](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3.10/reference/compound_stmts.html?highlight=while#while) no seu código. Veja [Por que em Python não há goto?](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3.10/faq/design.html#id25)

Comment: A dúvida que tenho é se há algo que faça com que eu não precise replicar a pergunta no código.

Comment: Então vou reformular. Por que pergunta sobre estruturas de repetição se já usa [estruturas de repetição](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3.10/reference/compound_stmts.html?highlight=while#while) em seu código?

Comment: Acho que eu já entendi o porquê de não ter como remeter a determinada linha de código com o link que você me passou sobre o fato de não existir goto no Python.

Entretanto, só para ficar claro, o que eu queria saber é se havia uma modo de não precisar replicar, mesmo que seja dentro de uma estrutura de repetição, uma mesma linha de código.

Answer (score -1):

Se entendi o seu problema basta usar uma função python para a operação que você quer repetir.
[Tutorial de funções](https://www.devmedia.com.br/funcoes-em-python/37340)

O seu código por exemplo poderia ser reescrito assim:

```py
numeros_por_extenso = [
    'zero', 'um', 'dois', 'três', 'quatro', 'cinco', 'seis', 'sete', 'oito', 'nove', 'dez', \
    'onze','doze', 'treze', 'quatorze', 'quinze', 'dezesseis', 'dezessete', 'dezoito', 'dezenove', 'vinte']

def retorna_numero_por_extenso():
    numero = int(input('Digite um número: '))
    numero_extenso = numeros_por_extenso[numero]
    print(f'Você digitou o número {numero_extenso}')

execucao = True

while execucao:
    retorna_numero_por_extenso()
    opcao = str(input('Quer continuar a ler os números por extenso? [S/N] ')).upper().strip()
    if opcao == 'N':
        execucao = False
        exit('Obrigado por usar nosso programa.')
```

Alguns detalhes:

- Procure não abreviar o nome das suas variáveis
- Não use mais de um laço while no mesmo código a menos que seja extremamente necessário.